# docker pull using puppet not working

Tags: docker, puppet, dockerfile, dockerhub, docker-registry

docker pull www.alm-docker-registry.com:8090/test... is working but when i am trying to do the same thing using puppet script, its showing error.

```
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Exec[Pulling Docker Image]/returns: 2015/01/30 11:11:11 Authentication is required.
Error: /usr/bin/docker pull www.alm-docker-registry.com:8090/test... returned 1 instead of one of [0]
Error: /Stage[main]/Main/Exec[Pulling Docker Image]/returns: change from notrun to 0 failed: /usr/bin/docker pull www.alm-docker-registry.com:8090/test... returned 1 instead of one of [0]
```

Note: I am not using any module but directly executing commands from manifest.

```
exec{'Pulling Docker Image':  
      command=>"/usr/bin/docker pull www.alm-docker-registry.com:8090/test... ,  
 }`
```

Comment: When you access the URL directly, are you authenticated ?

Comment: How are you running puppet? Specifically, what user is running puppet?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the error, it's saying that `Authentication is required.`. This could be the user that Puppet is running the docker exec as has different permissions that your default user.

Have you thought about using the [Docker module](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/garethr/docker)? It means you can perform the actions you want with, plus there's a lot of community support, and it makes the Docker actions idempotent so you won't get the commands running multiple times if not needed.